# Issue with filebeat kafka output lz4 compression

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat, lz4

I am trying to setup filebeat (6.2) with kafka output using lz4 compression, but always getting error as

```
ERR Invalid kafka configuration: kafka: invalid configuration (lz4 compression requires Version >= V0_10_0_0)
```

My output configuration is:

```
output.kafka:
hosts: ["kafka1:10092","kafka2:10092","kafka3:10092"]
topic: '%{[fields.log_topic]}'
partition.round_robin:
reachable_only: false

required_acks: 1
compression: lz4
max_message_bytes: 1000000
version: 0.11.0.0
```

Any insight on what might be wrong would be very helpful

Thanks.